# xcopy errorlevels returning zero and not 1 No files were found to copy

Tags: batch-file, errorlevel

In this batch script I'm testing the errorlevel return of expected `1`, but its echoing `0`.

If there is no file to copy, *folder is empty*, why would it return `0` for success?

I'm going by the following xcopy errorlevels:

> XCOPY should return the following exit codes:
>
> - 0 Files were copied without error.
> - 1 No files were found to copy.
> - 2 The user pressed CTRL+C to terminate xcopy.
> - 4 Initialization error occurred. There is not enough memory or disk space, or you entered an invalid drive name or invalid syntax on the command line.
> - 5 Disk write error occurred.

Here is my batch script:

```
@ECHO ON
SET ERRORS=0

REM Backup file first and report any errors if unsuccessful
xcopy /Y "C:\channels\filetransfer_process\*" "C:\channels\backup\"
echo %ERRORLEVEL%
REM Error Checking
REM Note The environmental variable ERRORLEVEL contains the return code of 
the last executed program or script.
if errorlevel 2 (
    SET BODY="not enough memory or disk space"
    GOTO :mailerror

)
if errorlevel 1 (
    SET BODY="No files were found to copy"
    GOTO :mailerror
)

if errorlevel 5 (
    SET BODY="Disk write error occurred"
    GOTO :mailerror
)
if NOT ["%errorlevel%"]==["0"] pause

REM Before doing the network connection make sure Z drive is free for use
if exist z:\ (  net use z: /delete )


REM proceed with a network connection using Z with error checking
net use Z: \\dcqwdbs034\D$\arrivals /user:sutter-chs\lawson Sutter1
if errorlevel 0 (
   goto :move
) else (
   SET BODY="net use connection failed"
   goto :mailerror
)

REM move file to MSCM server
:move
move /Y "C:\channels\filetransfer_process\*" "Z:\"
if errorlevel 1 (
    SET BODY="File not found, could not be moved/renamed or bad parameters"
    goto :mailerror
)

REM remove network mapped Z drive
net use z: /delete

REM perform the error notification via BLAT
:mailerror
"D:\Program Files\BLAT\blat.exe" -Install -Server mail1.sutterhealth.org -f 
 name@domain.org -u name@domain.org -Pw mypasswd
"D:\Program Files\BLAT\blat.exe" -To name@domain.org.org -Subject "File 
Transfer Error" -Body %BODY%
:EOF
```

Comment: As far as I know, [there is not any way](https://superuser.com/q/1180180/362853) for `xcopy` to return an `errorlevel 1`

Comment: Given that `XCopy` was superseded by `RoboCopy` more years ago than I can now remember, you could try using that instead. See [this](https://ss64.com/nt/robocopy-exit.html) for more information, in conjunction with the command's usage information `RoboCopy /?`

Answer (score 2):

Here is the batch file rewritten to handle all error conditions right (hopefully as not fully tested).

```
@echo off
REM Backup files first and report any errors if not successful
%SystemRoot%\System32\xcopy.exe "C:\channels\filetransfer_process\*" "C:\channels\backup\" /C /Q /Y >"%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"

REM Error checking
REM Note: The environment variable ERRORLEVEL contains the
REM       return code of  the last executed program or script.
if errorlevel 5 SET "BODY=File write error occurred" & GOTO MailError
if errorlevel 2 SET "BODY=Not enough memory or free space" & GOTO MailError
if not errorlevel 1 pause

set "FileCount=0"
for /F "usebackq" %%I in ("%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp") do set "FileCount=%%I"
if "FileCount" == "0" SET "BODY=No files were found to copy" & GOTO MailError

REM Temporary file with number of copied files as last line no longer needed.
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp"
set "FileCount="

REM Before doing the network connection make sure Z drive is free for use
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use Z: /delete 2>nul

REM Proceed with a network connection using Z with error checking.
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use /persistent:no
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use Z: \\dcqwdbs034\D$\arrivals password /user:domain\username
if errorlevel 1 SET "BODY=Net use connection failed" & GOTO MailError
if not exist Z:\ SET "BODY=Net use connection failed" & GOTO MailError

REM Move files to MSCM server.
move /Y "C:\channels\filetransfer_process\*" "Z:\"
if errorlevel 1 (
    %SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use Z: /delete
    SET "BODY=File not found, could not be moved/renamed or bad parameters"
    GOTO MailError
)

REM Remove network mapped Z drive.
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use Z: /delete
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use /persistent:yes
goto :EOF

REM Perform the error notification via BLAT.
:MailError
%SystemRoot%\System32\net.exe use /persistent:yes
del "%TEMP%\%~n0.tmp" 2>nul
"D:\Program Files\BLAT\blat.exe" -Install -Server mail1.sutterhealth.org -f name@domain.org -u name@domain.org -Pw mypasswd "D:\Program Files\BLAT\blat.exe" -To name@domain.org.org -Subject "File Transfer Error" -Body "%BODY%"
```

**XCOPY** is executed with option `/Q` to suppress output of copied files. But **XCOPY** outputs nevertheless as final summary information the number of copied files. This output is redirected into a temporary file for later evaluation. But first is the exit code of **XCOPY** evaluated.

`if errorlevel 2` means if exit code of command/application is **greater or equal** `2` and so `if errorlevel 5` must be the first **IF** condition.

`[` and `]` have no special meanings on a string comparison. They are just two literal characters. So don't add them on a string comparison. `if NOT "%errorlevel%"=="0" pause` would be absolutely enough.

The double quotes have a special meaning for command interpreter as marking begin/end of an argument string in which the characters should be interpreted literally with exception of `%` and `!` on delayed expansion enabled. But please note that `"` are always included by **IF** on comparing the two arguments. In other words `if` does not remove surrounding double quotes before comparing the arguments.

`ERRORLEVEL` has always an integer value assigned as string and therefore it is safe to use `if NOT %ERRORLEVEL% == 0 pause` to make the string comparison a bit faster because of just two bytes have to be compared (ASCII representation of `0` and string terminating null byte, i.e. 0x30, 0x00) instead of four bytes (quote byte, ASCII representation of `0`, quote byte and string terminating null byte, i.e. 0x22, 0x30, 0x22, 0x00).

But best is using `if not errorlevel 1` which means if exit code of previous command/application is **lower than** `1`. Nearly all applications exit with `0` on success and a positive number greater `0` on an error condition. Therefore `if not errorlevel 1` working also within a command block is nearly always better than `if %ERRORLEVEL% == 0` for testing on success.

The command **FOR** with option `/F` as used in this batch file reads the lines from specified file line by line, skips empty lines, skips lines starting with a semicolon, splits up each line into substrings using default delimiters space and horizontal tab and assigns first space/tab delimited string to specified loop variable `I`. In this case this should be always the number of copied files.

The application **NET** does often not exit with a value greater 0 on an error. So better verify if drive `Z:` really exists after mapping network share to a drive letter. It is also better making the network drive mapping not persistent stored in Windows registry of current user. BTW: The domain, user name and password posted in code in question are hopefully fake data.

For understanding the used commands and how they work, open a command prompt window, execute there the following commands, and read entirely all help pages displayed for each command very carefully.

- `del /?`
- `echo /?`
- `for /?`
- `goto /?`
- `move /?`
- `net /?`
- `net use /?`
- `pause /?`
- `rem /?`
- `set /?`
- `xcopy /?`

See also:

- [Where does GOTO :EOF return to?](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37518000/3074564)
- [Single line with multiple commands using Windows batch file](https://stackoverflow.com/a/25344009/3074564)